# How to form data for LSTM in keras

Tags: keras, lstm

I have 1000 samples, each sample has 9 features and 1 output. How can I form my data to the shape to use in LSTM?

Output looks like sawtooth. [image: output]

Right now my date is shaped to be 1000*1*9 ([samples, time_steps, features]). The performance is not very good. How can I include more time steps? Do I do a look back to reshape it to 998*3*9 (assume look_back =3)?  Also what is good guide for how much should I look-back?

Answer (score 2):

If you use a timestep of 1, you do not  get the advantages of the LSTM : the fact that they can 'remember' from the past. You should try with cross validation to find the timestep that give you the best performance or/and to choose it with the "context" behind your data.

And yes, if the look back is 3, you will have to reshape it to 998*3*9.

Comment: You can still have the LSTM layers remember their state with a step size of 1 if you build them with `stateful=True` (and care then to call `.reset_states()` after completing a batch of sequences).

Comment: Yes right, but in this case the states are going to be remembered between batches, so you are going to gain a finner control in the learning but at the end you will not learn "long term" depedencies : even if you remember from one batch to the other, if the timestep is one, you will not find depedencies in time. And souldn't you call `.reset_states()` after each epochs and not batches, if you have `stateful = True` ?

Comment: Yes, I agree that learning with a time step of 1 is far from ideal. As for epochs and batches, I guess its a matter of terminology. I was referring to a batch of complete sequences, which would be further divided into "chunks" with the size of the time step (1 in this case); so I meant resetting the state after you do all the "chunks" for a batch of sequences. Then I'd call an "epoch" a set of batches of sequences. But I think we're both referring to the same thing in any case.